# Обновление с JDK 6.0 до JDK 7.0 под Windows 7

Tags: windows, java

У меня установлена версия JDK 1.6.0.0_25, я так понимаю это JDK 6[image]

сегодня вышшла JDK 7.0. Как можно безболезненно обновиться до этой версии под Windows 7 ?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь 7-я уже месяца 3 назад вышла

Comment: публичный релиз был вчера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что там обновляться-то, это же Windows. [Качаете](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html) и устанавливаете.